# Regex to filter lines that don't contain coordinates in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file:

```
=====================================================================================================
        --NUO---    --IKI- ATSTUMAS                     MAKS.   NUKRYPIMAS    KATEGORIJA              
KELIAS    KM M       KM M      M  PARAMETRAS            REIKSME VIETA      ESAMA   GALIMA  LAIPSNIS   
=====================================================================================================
I          34,452    34,449     3 PERKRYPA                17    34,451     V       V-15    4  
                                                                     [55,47868125|21,43902188|   38]
I          34,396    34,393     3 PERKRYPA                19    34,395     V       V-15    4  
                                                                     [55,47913606|21,43864715|   37]
I          34,269    34,267     2 PERKRYPA               -14    34,268     V       VI      4  
                                                                     [55,48019067|21,43788667|   37]
I                    34,0         KM: 34 <1000>                      [55.48244916|21.43642915|   37]
I          33,678    33,675     3 PLOTIS1                -12    33,676     V       STOP    4  
                                                                     [55,48517892|21,43466534|   37]
I          33,645    33,642     3 PERKRYPA               -19    33,643     V       V-15    4  
                                                                     [55,48545685|21,43448551|   37]
```

I want to filter all the `PERKRYPA` lines and therefore leave only the coordinates (e.g `[55,47868125|21,43902188`) in the document, in order to copy all of them to another window.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with NotePad++ by doing a search and replace.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog.
2. For **Find what**, enter:

   ```
    ^.*?(PERKRYPA.*?\r\n\s*(\[.+?\]))|.*\r\n
   ```
3. For **Replace with**, enter:

   ```
    \2
   ```
4. Set **Search Mode** to be **Regular expression**.
5. Hit the **Replace All** button.

[image]

Comment: There full text file
[link]http://sharetext.org/3X1j

With notepad don't work for me.
But i want learn to use filter with notepad :)

Comment: What happens if you run it? You uploaded a .htm file, is that the original format, ie is it using CR + LF (Windows/DOS line feeds).

Answer (score -2):

So i always advice [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) cause it have nice text editing features. Anyway i describe some steps what i do to get this

use find text with next regexp

```
I .+PERKRYPA.+\n
```

or something like that, next press **find all** and you select all lines wich match your regexp
[image: pic1]

this text editor have multiselection feature, delete end line delimiter and youl have all data you need on one line.
[image]

Try search again and you'll have all data you need. Copy selected data and paste it to new tab. Enjoy;).

[image]

Comment: is this bad soluion?

Comment: It's not Notepad++.

Comment: i'm not advertise sublimetext2, but i think sometimes it's more easy to use, what wrong if i suggest another decision? i think it have place to be.